# Measure total wait time for a Windows executable

Tags: windows, performance

I am looking for a way to evaluate the degree to which performance is an issue for a certain application used by numerous users working on Windows Server 2003.

I know Windows 10 allows to display a process's CPU wait time, but my basic need is a measure of a process's total wait time - not just CPU wait time. I expect most of the processing time to be spent waiting after a reply from another server.

But a solution would be a lot more useful if:

1. It applied to Windows Server 2003
2. It could be used before the application is started, not just on a specific process. We would want a total for all instances of executable foo.exe, not just one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Each process instance runs in it's own PID (Process ID). So you would essentially have to do the math for the overall totals yourself on that.

Use Process explorer.
Per http://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson2/ one of the bullets states: "Very accurate CPU usage tracking for processes."

You can get it here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

Comment: I know Process Explorer, but I do not see how it can measure total wait time. Thanks, but as I wrote, CPU wait time may not even be most of the wait time for that application.